# Packaging tensorflow models as wheel files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, setup.py, python-wheel

I have created my tensorflow model which will act as a serve. Code will be hosted on client's local server. I don't want to give them my code but give them a wheel file. But after following python's package distribution my tensorflow files become corrupted.

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can send only the frozen inference graph in `.pb` format.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has its own APIs for serving that's [TensorFlow TFX Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving). You can check out this [great article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-models-using-tensorflow-serving-and-flask-508ba00f1037) on it.

As mentioned on their website,

> TensorFlow Serving makes it easy to deploy new algorithms and
>   experiments while keeping the same server architecture and APIs.
>   TensorFlow Serving provides out-of-the-box integration with TensorFlow
>   models but can be easily extended to serve other types of models and
>   data.

You can use the RESTful API as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest).

You can learn more from these articles:

https://medium.com/@zhanwenchen/deploy-a-trained-rnn-lstm-model-with-tensorflow-serving-and-flask-part-1-introduction-and-336dbb8f02f

https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-your-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-serving-and-kubernetes-9d9e78e569db

**Using RESTful API →**

https://medium.com/@yuu.ishikawa/introduction-to-restful-api-with-tensorflow-serving-9c60969b5b95

https://becominghuman.ai/creating-restful-api-to-tensorflow-models-c5c57b692c10